# Sublime text - Remember hidden code

Tags: hide, sublimetext

In sublime editor you can hide code like this:

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

However if I reopen this file, all code is visible again. How can I hide this code until I open it myself again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I installed BufferScrol with the package manager.